# Consulta a Mysql con Android

Tags: mysql, android

Desde android una vez el usuario inicia sesión en la aplicación, con el id de usuario hago una select a otra base de datos mysql con un fichero php. Lo que quiero hacer es comprobar si existe aluna fila que tenga ese valor en la columna id. Lo que no se es como comprobarlo en android el resultado de la select de php ya que he intentado hacerlo con un método que me retorne un boolean pero siempre me retorna que no existe.

El contenido del php:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$codigo=$_GET['codigo'];

$consulta="select uid from users where uid='$codigo'";
$resultado=$conexion-> query($consulta);

while($fila=$resultado->fetch_array()){
    $producto[]=array_map('utf8_encode',$fila);
}

echo json_encode($producto);
$resultado -> close();
?>
```

Y en el código java lo llamo de la siguiente forma, donde a.getuid me devuelve el valor que quiero buscar en la base de datos mysql

```
public boolean exist(Usuario a){
        existe=false;
        URL="http://ip/services/buscar.php?codigo="+a.getUid();
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                if(response.length()>0){
                    existe=true;
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("ERROR",error.getMessage());
            }
        }
        );
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(cont);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        return existe;
    }
```

Cuando llamo al método para comprobar si existe siempre me devuelve false independientemente de que el valor exista en la base de datos

El response del onResponde si lo muestro por pantalla con un toString me muestra:

```
D/SRV: [{"0":"zHTbpddy6ofauLnMeVKHcn1d2Ap1","uid":"zHTbpddy6ofauLnMeVKHcn1d2Ap1"}]
```

Comment: Tu segunda funcion exists, es js? donde es que esta? ahi hay una promesa.. estas seguro que la funcion vuelve despues de ejecutar la promesa? si no, siempre va a devolver falso...

Comment: seguramente el problema sea que la funcion lo devuelve antes, pero como puedo controlar eso?

Comment: @gbianchi tienes razón Gonzalo, aunque se obtenga la respuesta y se valide correctamente como es un proceso asincrono , el método siempre retornara true.

Comment: ya los agarro al vuelo estos errores jajajaja...

Comment: entonces como podría comprobar si existe ese valor en la base de datos?

Comment: si lo hago en un proceso asincrono y en el on postexecute hago la comprobación me funcionaría? o cual sería la forma correcta?

Comment: Tu código Android es correcto, al menos en apariencia. Pero no sabemos si está conectando correctamente con el servidor. Volley ya tiene su propio método para manejar las respuestas asíncronas (para eso es el `onResponse`), entonces, dentro de ese método haz un Log de `response` con algo así: `Log.d("SRV",response);` y dinos qué muestra al lado de  `SRV`. Ni siquiera sabemos si hay comunicación cliente/servidor y si la hay qué devuelve.

Comment: Comunicación la hay, voy a hacer el log de response y lo adjunto

Comment: @A.Cedano he realizado el Log.d del response.toString(); y me muestra la fila de lo que realizo el select, ya que actualmente existe ese valor en la bd, pero me retorna false

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120352/discussion-on-question-by-javi-ruiz-consulta-a-mysql-con-android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente te sugiero usar [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) para validar si existen registros en la base de datos:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
$codigo=$_GET['codigo'];
$consulta="select uid from users where uid='$codigo'";
$resultado=$conexion-> query($consulta);

$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
  echo json_encode("OK");
}
else {
  echo json_encode("");
}
$resultado -> close();
```

de esta forma al obtener el valor "OK" en la respuesta determinará que existe un registro en la base de datos:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                if(response.length()>0){
                    existe=true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Pero el punto importante de tu pregunta es el mètodo `exist(Usuario a)` el cual espera obtener un valor boolean pero como comenta @gbianchi el `JsonArrayRequest` realiza un proceso asincrono el valor de `existe` puede no ser correcto.

Te sugiero que en lugar de llamar el mètodo, llamès el mètodo en el cual existe el usuario, ejemplo suponiendo que `procesoExisteUsuario()` realiza el trabajo cuando el usuario existe.

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                if(response.length()>0){
                    
                    //Existe usuario!
                    procesoExisteUsuario(); 

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("ERROR",error.getMessage());
            }
        }
        );
        requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(cont);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: Joge no sera problema de la promesa?

Comment: @gbianchi  es que siempre al parecer esta respondiendo algún valor aquí: echo json_encode($producto); entonces aquí siempre le daría true:  public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                if(response.length()>0){ , por cierto el jsonArrayRequest siempre esperaría a la respuesta de la petición,

Comment: claro pero me pa que su funcion existe se fue antes de la respuesta...

Comment: @gbianchi , gran fallo mió por no ver esa parte, tienes razón!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :-|

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, para dar soluciòn :-)

Comment: Si, se solucionó llamando directamente al lo que quería hacer dentro del onResponse, en php no estoy muy puesto entonces apañé un código que encontré pero efectivamente lo tengo que corregir, muchas gracias por la ayuda con el php tambien

Comment: Excelente Javi, saludos.